# MySQL query- join and concatenate when condition, else null

Tags: mysql, left-join, group-concat

I have a table of recipes and a table of images.

Recipes:

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'Pancake' |
| 2 | 'Pudding' |
| 3 | 'Pizza' |

Images:

| id | recipe_id | url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 'images\pancake1' |
| 2 | 1 | 'images\pancake2' |
| 3 | 2 | 'images\pizza |

I want to join recipes with images.url and concatenate the urls as such:

| recipe_id | urls |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'images\pancake1, images\pancake2' |
| 2 | 'images\pizza' |
| 3 | null |

But I get:

| recipe_id | urls |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | 'images\pancake1, images\pancake2, images\pizza' |
| 3 | null |

My query is :

```
SELECT r.*,
CASE WHEN i.recipe_id = r.id THEN
 GROUP_CONCAT(i.url)
 END AS url
FROM recipes r
JOIN images i
GROUP BY r.id;
```

Comment: to kopy pretty-formatted SQL comnmands and data use https://dbfiddle.uk and its Markdown Export button

Comment: so i was correct on `LEFT OUTER JOIN` the first comment i posted by gut feelings, then got doubts and removed it... read about outer and inner joins at "Essential SQL" book or at least at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join does not even have an `ON` clause.
You need a `LEFT` join:

```
SELECT r.id recipe_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(i.url ORDER BY i.id) urls
FROM Recipes r LEFT JOIN Images i
ON i.recipe_id = r.id
GROUP BY r.id
```

Comment: Beautiful. I had the same on clause but left join did the trick.

Comment: @MosheM you can also add Title column by pseudo-aggregating,. see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=22655cda7b930bcdaed0aa717958c027